# ExpressionEngine control panel links use wrong URL

Tags: control-panel, php, url, path

I'm attempting to set up a staging server for a live EE powered website. I decided to use xampp but I'm having problems getting everything working.

On the live website EE's control panel links look like this

```
index.php?S=098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=8&entry_id=87
```

But on my staging setup the same link looks like this

```
index.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form&channel_id=8&entry_id=87&S=098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

The result is an immediate refresh back to the main page of the control panel: I'm unable to navigate further.

I've updated the config.php, index.php, database.php files with the correct paths. Does anyone have any experience with an issue like this?

Comment: are you sure that you update all files? Because the second url (which u see for staging) is correct url for EE >=2.8.

Comment: Ah yes! I did try to run the Updater addon to update the site to latest EE but it did not work, it must have updated part of the files. When I tried to revert I forgot to copy over all of the folders. Thank you everything is working now!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not completed update process

Comment: Good that it was easy case for you )